# Selecting multiple & random values with limit

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, random, implode

I have this code here:

```
$ids = implode(',', array_rand(array_column($test, 'id', 'id'), 5));
```

Here's what that code above does:

"First extract the id column indexing also by the id, then pick 5 random ones, and finally implode into a comma separated list. Since keys must be unique, this has the added benefit of not returning duplicate ids if there happen to be duplicates in the array" this is from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084925/select-multiple-random-values-by-key-from-arrays)

Now if I change my `$arr` from my old question to this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 13
    [pets] => 8
    [num_of_times] => 3
)
Array
(
    [id] => 15
    [pets] => 8
    [num_of_times] => 6
)
Array
(
    [id] => 16
    [pets] => 10
    [num_of_times] => 2
)
Array
(
    [id] => 17
    [pets] => 9
    [num_of_times] => 4
)
Array
(
    [id] => 18
    [pets] => 10
    [num_of_times] => 3
)
Array
(
    [id] => 19
    [pets] => 10
    [num_of_times] => 10
)
Array
(
    [id] => 20
    [pets] => 0
    [num_of_times] => 11
)
Array
(
    [id] => 21
    [pets] => 8
    [num_of_times] => 9
)
Array
(
    [id] => 22
    [pets] => 9
    [num_of_times] => 0
)
Array
(
    [id] => 23
    [pets] => 4
    [num_of_times] => 3
)
Array
(
    [id] => 24
    [pets] => 0
    [num_of_times] => 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 40
    [pets] => 8
    [num_of_times] => 0
)
Array
(
    [id] => 43
    [pets] => 2
    [num_of_times] => 2
)
```

`num_of_times` is the number of times that `id` or "user" can be selected.

So if I had a `for loop` like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $ids = implode(',', array_rand(array_column($arr, 'id', 'id'), 5));
    echo $ids;
}
```

how can I make sure, for example, the first array with id **13** does **NOT** go into `$ids` more than 3 times but CAN go into `$ids` 3 times OR less, when in the `for loop`? (this applies for all the id's)

For example, the final result would be something like this:

```
13,15,17,19,23
13,21,22,40,43
13,15,17,19,23
15,23,24,40,43 // 13 cannot be selected anymore because it already hit the "num_of_times" limit which is 3 for the number 13. Same thing for all the other numbers/id's
...
...
...
...
...
...
```

Comment: If you want to use your current code, this will become very arbitrary code. Best use would be writing a recursive function and ditching your current code. If you generate 5 unique ids from the arrays and then check if all 5 are okay to use due to num_of_times, you must generate 5 that fit, and ditch all of them if one of them can't be used anymore. Using a recursive function, you can generate 1 id and check if you can still use it. This will be more efficient.

Comment: Does same number on one line not valid? E.g. `13, 13, 15, 17, 19`

Comment: @Motbrok Can you point me in the right direction with what functions to use, etc?

Comment: @Erwin Cannot have duplicate numbers

Comment: What if only 3 ids haven't reached their `num_of_times`, would the line be just 3 digits? E.g. `19, 20, 21` *(Since they have high num_of_times)* Or is there enough data to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Erwin Sorry to mention but there is enough data to prevent this from happening. What should I do to construct a script for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to solve this

```
$num = array_column($test, 'num_of_times', 'id'); // get each num_of_times with id as index
for ($ids = '', $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {         // Your for loop
    $num = array_filter($num);                    // Filter $num array
    $rand = array_rand($num, 5);                  // get 5 random element
    $ids .= implode(',', $rand) . '<br>';         // implode then concatenate to $ids var
    foreach ($rand as $id) {                      // Run a foreach loop to $rand array
        $num[$id]--;                              // Decrement num_of_times
    }
}
echo $ids;  // Echo result
```

Comment: +1 for doing it with decrement of num_of_times :) makes using recursive functions obsolete. Does need an error catch when not enough options are given tho.

Answer (score 1):

Hi bro try my code if it fits to your needs. You just need to add more array data if you want to limit the use of each data.

```
<?php

$arr = Array(Array
(
   'id' => 13,
   'pets' => 8,
   'num_of_times' => 3
),Array(
   'id' => 15,
  'pets' => 8,
  'num_of_times' => 6
),Array (
'id' => 16,
'pets' => 10,
'num_of_times' => 2
),Array(
'id' => 17,
'pets' => 9,
'num_of_times' => 4
),Array(
'id' => 18,
'pets' => 10,
'num_of_times' => 3
),Array(
'id' => 19,
'pets' => 10,
'num_of_times' => 10
),Array(
'id' => 20,
'pets' => 0,
'num_of_times' => 11
),Array(
'id' => 21,
'pets' => 8,
'num_of_times' => 9
),Array(
'id' => 22,
'pets' => 9,
'num_of_times' => 0
),Array(
'id' => 23,
'pets' => 4,
'num_of_times' => 3
),Array(
'id' => 24,
'pets' => 0,
'num_of_times' => 1
),Array(
'id' => 40,
'pets' => 8,
'num_of_times' => 0
),Array(
'id' => 43,
'pets' => 2,
'num_of_times' => 2,
));


$checker = array(); //array that holds the id with the count of use
$remove =array(); // array to remove in array to random 

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

$newArray =array_diff(array_column($arr, 'id', 'id'),$remove); //the newarray to use in random with remove function for the id that has been used for 3x

$ids = array_rand($newArray, 5); 

foreach($ids as $id){

    if(!array_key_exists($id,$checker)){ // check if the id is existing in the checker key if yes

        $checker[$id] = 1; // insert value 1 in the array as the count of use

    }else{

        if(!empty($checker[$id]) && $checker[$id] < 3){ //check if the array has a value lower than 3

            $checker[$id]=$checker[$id]+1; // then add 1 value for the data as a increment of data usage

            if($checker[$id] == 3){ //check if da is already used 3x
                $remove[]=$id; //then add it to the variable remove
            }
        }
    }




}
echo implode(',',$ids).'</br>';

}

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($checker);
echo '</pre>';
```